# std::bad_cast when using std::basic_istringstream<unsigned short>

Tags: c++, string, gcc, istringstream, stdstring

I'm trying to process UTF-16 string (placed in a buffer `buf`) with the help of `std::basic_string` and `istringstream`. An exception `std::bad_cast` occurs in this code. Is there a problem with my code? Or gcc's STL just cannot handle `unsigned int` (16 bit) symbols?

```
const unsigned short * buf;
// ... fiilling buf
std::basic_string<unsigned short> w(buf);
std::basic_istringstream<unsigned short> iss(w);

unsigned int result;
try { iss >> result; }
catch (std::exception& e)
{
   const char * c = e.what();
}
```

The same code with `std::wstring` and `std::wistringstream` works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiation of IOStreams on different character types than `char` and `wchar_t` is rather non-trivial. The streams need a number of `std::locale` facets to be present. Without them they won't function properly. For the attempted operation you'd need, at least:

- `std::ctype<cT>`
- `std::numpunct<cT>`
- `std::num_get<cT>`

where `cT` is the stream's character type. The last one of these should just require instantiation but the others need to be implemented. Of course, you also need to make sure a `std::locale` is installed for the stream by either setting it up as the global locale or using `stream.imbue()`.

Personally, I think this is overall the wrong approach, though: the characters should be converted into an internal representation when entering the system and converted to an external representation when leaving the system (that's the purpose of the `std::codecvt<...>` facet). It seems, however, that this is a lost fight and people feel they want to mess with encodings internally.

Comment: Thanks, this explains. What if I have a valid wide string that just happens to be stored as an array of `unsigned short`? Can I somehow use `std::wstring` for processing it without manually converting array of shorts to array of `wchar_t`? The problem is simply that `wchar_t` is 4 bytes on my platform.

Comment: Assuming your source data is UTF-16 encoded, I'd guess the approach would be to convert it into the internal `wchar_t` encoding.